# Can Link Books be renamed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Whenever I make a mystcraft linkbook its name is 'Linking Book'. Can I rename this book somehow so its name is one I can reference to easily?

Note: The Anvil will do this, costing you seven levels, but I'm looking for a way to do this without using an Anvil.

Answer (score 5):

By putting the Link Book in the bottom left slot of a Writing Table, one can rename it, experience free.